# Solve equation: $\cos x\cos 2x\cos(3x-\frac{\pi}{3} ) = \frac{1}{2}+ \sin x \sin 2x \sin 3x$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve equation: $\cos x\cos 2x\cos(3x-\frac{\pi}{3} ) = \frac{1}{2}+ \sin x \sin 2x \sin 3x$

I guess $\sin x=0$ may be one of the roots. I've been trying very hard to factor polynomials but was unable to solve it. Can anyone help, please?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Do you use product to some formula?  for example use $$cos x cos (2x) =\frac 12 (cos 3x+cos x)\\sin(x)sin(2x)=\frac {-1}{2}(cos (3x)-cos(x))$$

Comment: yes I've tried but can't solve

Comment: I have no idea how to solve $\cos (3x-\frac{\pi}{3} )$

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}=\cos(3x-\frac{π}{3} -3x)=\cos(3x)\cos(3x-\frac{π}{3})+\sin(3x)\sin(3x-\frac{π}{3})$

Comment: Again I've tried to use some formulas but it didn't help solving this. Please help me!!!
$\cos (3x-\frac{π}{3}) \sin2x = (3 - 4 \sin^2x) \sin (3x - \frac {π}{3}) + \sin2x \sin3x$

Comment: One thing you can do, but is a lot of work is using complex numbers, $\cos{x} = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and $\sin{x} = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$, expand and then you can write $z = e^{2ix}$ and you will have a polynomial equation of degree 6, but you can check that $x=0$ (like you said) and $x=-\frac{\pi}{4}$ are roots, which translate to $z=1$ and $z=-i$, so you can divide the polynomial by $(z-1)(z+i)$, I don't know if gets easier after than that